# Can we put 2 conditions in a single if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wanna ask if we can put 2 or more conditions in single 'if'
For example:

```
if a == 1 b == 2:
     print 'can we do this? If yes, how? '
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that both are true, use `and`:

```
if (a == 1) and (b == 2):
```

"If `a` equals 1 *and* `b` equals 2 ...".

Look up logical operators for other similar operations.

Answer (score 1):

For both conditions to be true

```
if condition1 and condition2:
```

For one of the conditions to be true

```
if condition1 or condition2:
```